# Jquery: How to move ajax post list data from action to other action successfully?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeFDz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiIHU.png)

İ try to send with ajax table data. Data can pass successfully passing to action as a parameter.
But When i try to passed  data to another action via redirect to action method then it is being null.
in summary i need to get this data and view on different page. So for this situation i need to use [HTTPGET] action.
Summary

*i can pass data post action in MVC
*When i redirect to other action list data being null
*i want to use that Ajax Posted data  and view on Razor.

$("#BtnCreateOrderLast").click(function () {

```
    var aData = [];

    $("#tblDemo tbody tr").each(function () {

        var currentRow = $(this);
        var ProductName = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
        var ProductCode = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
        var Cost = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").html();
        var Stock = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
        var Konsinye = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").html();
        var CountOfProduct = currentRow.find("td:eq(5) input").val();




        var obj = {};
        obj.ProductName = ProductName;
        obj.ProductCode = ProductCode;
        obj.Cost = Cost;
        obj.Stock = Stock;
        obj.Konsinye = Konsinye;
        obj.CountOfProduct = CountOfProduct;


        if (currentRow.find(".ChangeWidthF").is(":checked")) {

            aData.push(obj);

        }


    })


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Order/CreateOrderWithButtonCheckedProducts',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "ProductViewModel": aData },
        success: function (result) {



        }

    });





})
```

---

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateOrderWithButtonCheckedProduct(List<ProductViewModel> result)
    {
      


        return View();

    }




    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateOrderWithButtonCheckedProducts(List<ProductViewModel> productViewModel)
      {



        return RedirectToAction("CreateOrderWithButtonCheckedProduct", "Order",productViewModel);

    }
```

Comment: Could you attached your actual code snippet to investigate better, Attach both your ajax and controller code.

Comment: Which action you are talking about `" But When i try to passed data to another action via redirect to action method then it is being null"` Could you please share your actions as well.

Comment: as summary i want to move productviewmodel to CreateOrderWithButtonCheckedProduct action and show in different page

Comment: `show in different page`Do you mean you want to redirect to different page rather than current page?

Comment: Yes! but also i want to pass productViewModel list another action and then show different page with proceed productViewModel data.

Comment: Got your point, wait a while checking your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectToAction()` method takes **two parameters:** the name of the action you want to redirect to, and an `object` that contains the data you want to pass as parameters.

Example:

```
return RedirectToAction("ExampleMethod", new {data = myData });
```

In the `ExampleMethod` you can define a parameter with the same name as the one you passed.

```
public ActionResult ExampleMethod(List<MyClass> data)
{
    // Do something with the data
    return View(data);
}
```

One thing you should know is that the data you are passing as a parameter must be serializable and it should match the parameter type defined in the action you are redirecting to.

If the method you redirect to is in a another controller, you can use `querystring` to pass the data to another action.

Example:

```
return RedirectToAction("ExampleMethod", "ExampleController", new { data = myData });
```

and in the action you can fetch the data from `querystring`.

```
public ActionResult ExampleMethod()
{
    var myData = Request.QueryString["data"];
    // Do something with the data
    return View(myData);
}
```

If you **don't** want to use `RedirectToAction()` method, you can also use `Session[]` or `TempData[]` to pass the data.

Session Example:

```
Session["MyData"] = myData;
```

Then, in the second action where you want to display the data, you can retrieve the data from the session using the following code:

```
var myData = (List<MyClass>)Session["MyData"];
```

TempData Example:

```
TempData["MyData"] = myData;
```

In the second action where you want to display the data:

```
var myData = (List<MyClass>)TempData["MyData"];
```